# Checkboxes not working, they all control the original one created I have adjusted many times and cant seem to get it right

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

Checkboxes are being created in displayBookCard() but Im not understanding whats causing this. I ended up adding a spexific class to each individual checkbox but doesnt seem to help.

https://codepen.io/migijc/pen/QWQRwvN

```
let displayBookCards = function (index){
    let bookCard= document.createElement("div");
    let removeButton=document.createElement("button")
    removeButton.textContent="Remove Book"
    let titleToDisplay=document.createElement('h4');
    titleToDisplay.classList.add("titleToDisplay")
    let authorToDisplay=document.createElement("h4");
    let pagesToDisplay= document.createElement('h4');
    let hasReadToDisplay=document.createElement('h4')
    booksGrid.appendChild(bookCard)
    bookCard.appendChild(titleToDisplay)
    bookCard.appendChild(authorToDisplay)
    bookCard.appendChild(pagesToDisplay)
    bookCard.appendChild(hasReadToDisplay);
    bookCard.appendChild(removeButton);
    removeButton.classList.add("removeButton")
    bookCard.classList.add("bookCards")
    body.appendChild(booksGrid)
    myLibrary.forEach((item) => {
        titleToDisplay.textContent=item.bookName
        authorToDisplay.textContent= `By: ${item.bookAuthor}`;
        pagesToDisplay.textContent=`Pages: ${item.bookPages}`;
        hasReadToDisplay.textContent=`Book Read: ${item.bookRead}`;
    });
        // bookCard.appendChild(toggleButtonContainer)
        booksGrid.classList.add("showing")
        removeBook(removeButton);
        bookCard.setAttribute("data-index", index)
        addClassToRemoveButton(removeButton)
        removeClassFromRemoveButton(removeButton)
        appendToggle(bookCard, index)
```

};

```
  let appendToggle= function (bookCard,index) {
    let toggleButtonContainer=document.createElement("div")
    let toggleButton=document.createElement("input")
    let toggleLabel=document.createElement('label')
    toggleButtonContainer.setAttribute("class", "toggleButtonContainer")
    toggleButton.setAttribute("value", "notRead")
    toggleButton.setAttribute("type","checkbox")
    toggleButton.setAttribute("class", "toggle")
    toggleButton.setAttribute("name", "toggleStatus")
    toggleButton.setAttribute("id", "toggleStatus")
    toggleLabel.setAttribute("for", "toggleStatus")
    toggleButtonContainer.appendChild(toggleButton)
    toggleButtonContainer.appendChild(toggleLabel)
    bookCard.appendChild(toggleButtonContainer)
    toggleButton.classList.add(index)
  }
```

Comment: You are giving them all the same id here: `toggleButton.setAttribute("id", "toggleStatus")` so any script looking for that id will find the first one and stop, as valid html will not repeat an id.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much. The little details always get me!

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements within the context of a single web page must have unique ID attributes.

Because all of your checkboxes have an ID of "toggleStatus", and the labels are all "for" that same status, they all control the first instance of the checkbox.